# How to get the key value from the AppSettings.Config file?

Tags: c#, appsettings

I'm trying to get my key value set in the appsettings.Config file but seems not working.

This is what i wrote for that. The code is called from the constructor of an MDI file and its returning only null value. Anybody know why?

```
     var getValue = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ShowQueryTextbox"];
```

I also tried with ConfigurationManager.AppSettings . That too didnt work.

My AppSettings Code is as follows.

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ShowQueryTextbox" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Does the `ShowQueryTextbox` match case wise in the config file and the code?

Comment: Beware it case sensitive .. would you mind showing the config

Comment: Can you add details as if there are other projects mapped and where exactly is this placed and named as, Could be possible that its not being called at all

Comment: There's nothing more than this i wrote. I mean, im trying to call this from the constructor of my mdi file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue arise on renaming the App.Config file as AppSettings.Config. Thanks for all the guidances and help.

Comment: In a test scenario, we don't know ahead of time which key we are loading. We load ALL keys into a dictionary for use. So getting the key your suggested way means we have to know the key name, and we don't have that info at run time.

Answer (score 29):

ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings are obsolete, try

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ShowQueryTextbox"];
```

Comment: He has already mentioned using `ConfigurationManager` didn't work for him

Comment: Thanks, that is what I needed. Even if it didn't answer the question.

Answer (score 13):

Remember that to use:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyKey"];
```

You need to add reference to **System.Configuration** to your project.

Answer (score 1):

The `ConfigurationManager` is still up to date - Year 2017.

Btw, if you simply want to convert the appsettings configuration value from string to bool, then use `Convert.ToBoolean`

```
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnableLoggingInfo"]))
    {
        log.Info(message);
    }
```

In your appsettings configuration (web.config)

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="EnableLoggingInfo" value="true" />

  </appSettings>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am able to get like this:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("KEY").ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have added it to the required config file, Can you check the case of the key you are trying to access it's case sensitive so if you have keyed in a different case, it won't be returning the expected value.

Comment: It's the same as i copy-pasted it from config file.

Comment: Highly unlikely of something like this happening,could you rebuild and try since that would be only file to look when accessing via `ConfigurationManager`

Comment: Is there anything to do with this header in my config file? <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

Comment: Not at all that's fine, Can you check in the debug folder whether you are getting these values in the xml file there ?

Comment: I dont know which file to refer.

Comment: It would be named as appname.exe.config that is the configuration file else you are adding it in the wrong file, Are there multiple ?

Comment: I got a desktop as well as web project within the same solution. On creating the desktop project didnt created any config file. I added that manually and wrote the above code in my post. There is a web.config file in my webproject too. I couldnt find the file you referred in my debug folder.

Comment: V4Vendetta...Thanks for the help. The issue arise on renaming the App.Config file as AppSettings.Config.

Answer (score 0):

This error can also arise if you have the appsettings in the wrong configuration file - example in a WCF application it should be the one in the hosting project

Answer (score 0):

Check `Properties.Settings.Default.ShowQueryTextbox`.

Comment: Please don't give one-line answers! See [what is concidered a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on [so]! Thank you!